# Bootstrap - How to use ajax inside callback validation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a list of input elements whose id will be generated like user[0].firstName, user[1].firstName... Now i want to write a common validator for all these inputs. So i added a class called userName to them and tried to use remote validator but I'm unable to get the value of field which triggered the validator. It will be good if either one of them could work.

```js
                firstName: {
                  selector: '.userName',
                  validators: {
                    remote: {
                      url: '/servers/checkName',
                      type: 'POST',
                      dataType: "json",
                      data: function() {

                        // var user_name = document.getElementById("user0.firstName").value+"";
                        //here i need to get the value of field which called this validator
                        return {
                          name: user_name
                        };

                      },
                      message: ' user name is already exist'
                    },
                    callback: {
                      callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                        alert($field + " " + value);
                        return :{
                            //here im not able to ajax call like this
                            ajax({
                              url: '/servers/checkName',
                              type: 'POST',
                              dataType: "json",
                              data: value,
                              success: function(response) {
                                return response;
                              }
                            })


                          },
                          message: 'User Call back!'
                      }

                    }
                  },


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think callback, combined with ajax in it, wont work, because the response of the ajax request is async. So according the documentation [here](http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/validators/remote/) , the **remote** validator is what we should use. It works fine in my projects.

You have to change the **remote** validator like this:

```
remote: {
    url: '/servers/checkName',
    data: function(validator) {
        return {
            name: validator.getFieldElements('firstName').val()
        };
    },
}
```